# Changing the font for alert in beamer for math mode

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to change the font of the alerted text in my beamer, I want it to be in bold, in both text and math mode. I tried using boldmath but it doesn't work :

```
\begin{frame}{Test}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=vertf}

\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{family=\sffamily, series=\bfseries\boldmath}

$$\alert<2>{x} + \alert<3>{y} + \alert<4>{z}$$

\begin{itemize}
    \item <2-| alert@2>x 
    \item <3-| alert@3>y 
    \item <4-| alert@4>z
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Won't give you bold math, but at least avoid the error: `\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\ifmmode\else\bfseries\fi}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around the problem with something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green}


\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries\boldmath}

\renewcommand<>{\alert}[1]{%
  \ifmmode\text{%
    \begin{alertenv}#2\relax$#1$\end{alertenv}%
  }%
  \else%
    \begin{alertenv}#2\relax#1\end{alertenv}%
  \fi%
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}


\[
\alert<2>{x} + \alert<3>{y} + \alert<4>{z}
\]

\begin{itemize}
    \item <2-| alert@2>x 
    \item <3-| alert@3>y 
    \item <4-| alert@4>z
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but it produce an error : Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate - "You meant to type ## instead of #, right? Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##."

Comment: @armandfavrot Please make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce this error

Comment: @armandfavrot Don't do this within the frame. Move the stuff to the preamble as in my answer